# Accessing content field values in page layout using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I need the values of content type column(content field). I want to retrieve them using jquery so that I can give titles as those values.

Can I get values from the content field :

```
<div>
    <!--CS: Start Page Field: Tab Snippet-->
    <!--SPM:<%@Register Tagprefix="PageFieldLookupField" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"%>-->
    <!--MS:<PageFieldLookupField:LookupField FieldName="9a1672e8-e64f-46e6-b885-5c5872b514f1" runat="server">-->
        <!--PS: Start of READ-ONLY PREVIEW (do not modify)--><div align="left" class="ms-formfieldcontainer"><div class="ms-formfieldlabelcontainer" nowrap="nowrap"><span class="ms-formfieldlabel" nowrap="nowrap">Tab</span></div><div class="ms-formfieldvaluecontainer"></div></div><!--PE: End of READ-ONLY PREVIEW-->
    <!--ME:</PageFieldLookupField:LookupField>-->
    <!--CE: End Page Field: Tab Snippet-->
</div>
```

I'm editing page layout in html.

Comment: what value do you need there in your template ?

Comment: I have a custom content type with a column tab(lookup from list column). Now I need to retrieve values of column tab using jquery in page layout.

Comment: Please help me out

Comment: I don't understand the question please make it clear

Comment: I have a page content type. I created a column "Tabs", a lookup. It takes values from a list column. Now I created a page layout using this content type. I'm going to write a jquery in which I need the values in the "Tabs" column. Can I retrieve those values using jquery or any means?

Comment: Can I access the values of content type column in my page layout using jquery ????